# ajax jquery form fetching mysql data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have troubles with JQuery and Ajax forms. I'm new in Ajax and Jquery. I'm creating a webapp with a search form. The data I'm fetching from MYSQL Database. So I have a request page with a form, then the mysql processing file, a javascript to return the requested data and a html file, where the results are displayed. So, my problem is, that I can't display the results under index.html. Therefore I tried to action directly to landmarks.php and there I can see the reuslts in array like this

```
([{"id":"1","name":"Big Ben","latitude":"51.500600000000","longitude":"-0.124610000000"}]);
```

The request.html file

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Updated - loading external data into a PhoneGap app using jQuery 1.5</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>




<body>
<form method="post" action="landmarks.php">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="l_name"><b>Name</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="l_name" id="l_name" value="" />
                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>


</body>
```

Then this file for mysql

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$server = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "test132";
$database = "landmarks";

$l_name = $_POST["l_name"];

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$sql = "SELECT id, l_name AS name, l_lat AS latitude, l_long AS longitude FROM landmarks WHERE l_name like '".$l_name."' ORDER BY l_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

my json callback looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('#output');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'landmarks.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                var landmark = '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>'
                + '<p>'+item.latitude+'<br>'
                + item.longitude+'</p>';

                output.append(landmark);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.')
        }
    });
});
```

and finally my final page, where the results should be displayed

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Updated - loading external data into a PhoneGap app using jQuery 1.5</title>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/load-json.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **index.html** ?? change it to **index.php**

Comment: Use PDO or Mysqli please

Comment: I give you one advice. Don't use jQuery until you are able to solve this kind of problems with pure JavaScript. Only after that you will have ability to use jQuery in a right way.

Comment: i'm not sure about how correct your php code is but there is a broblem in your jquery code.
on success you are expecting the result to be an array of things to do a `$.each` but in php you are not sending a valid `json` result . because your result is something like `jsoncallback(your_mark_json);`  and that couldn't be parsed
i think you should not concatinate `json_encode()` output because it will not be parsed successfully in javascript.
Try to `echo json_encode()` directly